# I was invited to a smart contract reward approval, and i lost my all tokens at my trust wallet. Is The web site http:/ephbz.top a trap?

Tags: blockchain, wallets, scam, reward, trust

I was invited to a smart contract reward approval, and i lost my all tokens at my trust wallet.  Is The web site http:/ephbz.top a trap?

Comment: Also, please provide any additional information you can here so that StackExchange users don't have to click on that link to fully understand your issue.

Comment: [I added a generic question and answer: I got scammed](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-on-ethereum-what-to-do/152374#152374).

Comment: I'd say that with 99% of confidence it is a scam site. It doesn't provide any information about the project or its participants. Without a wallet it doesn't allow to visit it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you sign any transactions on this website that you didn't fully understand? If so, then you may have given users permission to spend your balance.

For future reference, never use a wallet with real money in it to sign transactions you aren't fully cognizant of. Also, make sure you generate a new account as your current wallet is likely compromised.